# Generic Start & end date of Half Year (Finacial Year) , PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to produce the generic half year Start & end date for a given date.

1. if I have `2019-01-10`, I would like to return `2018-10-01` & `2019-03-31`
2. if I have `2019-07-01`, I would like to return `2019-04-01` & `2019-09-30`

I can get the half year number (1 Or 2) and year:

This is Similar to [Quarter start & end date](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179874/generic-end-date-of-quarter-postgresql), but I need half yearly.
Financial year always starts April to March of respective year. No need the result in single function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try subtracting 3 months from the input date, and then check whether the resulting date fall within the first or second half of the year:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(month FROM input_date) - INTERVAL '3 MONTH'
              BETWEEN 1 AND 6 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS fiscal_half
FROM yourTable;
```

The trick here is to just shift your non standard fiscal year back to a normal 12 month year.  Once we have done that, we can easily figure out from which half of the year came each date.

Comment: Thanks a  lot @Tim for giving a logic.